# Using `interval` in a sentence

Tags: american-english

I've come across a case where I'm not sure how to structure a sentence around the word 'interval'. Out of the following sentences, which one(s) is(are) correct?

- Define the interval at which X does Y
- Define the interval between which X does Y

I've found occurrences of both but it seems using 'between' is more common.

Comment: Sorry, I just remembered that "over the interval" Is the usual construction. So "the interval _over_ which X does Y" Is more likely.

Comment: 'Define the interval ...' would only be used idiomatically when using the mathematical sense of 'interval', but the maths tag isn't included. 'Define the interval **on** which lnx < 0·6' is standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I** Supposing a case of definition which is not mathematical, and which, although [**user Edwin Ashworth's comment**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/551990/using-interval-in-a-sentence/551993?noredirect=1#comment1359082_551990) would find it unidiomatic, I would find only rare, the following can be said as pertains to an interval of time.

"Interval between which" is very rare compared with two other options with the same meaning and it should be avoided in my opinion because it is not logical.
"**Interval at which**" is all right but "**interval during which**" is preferred.  This and the rarity of "interval between which" can be verified in [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interval+at+which%2Cinterval+during+which%2Cinterval+between+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterval%20at%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterval%20during%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterval%20between%20which%3B%2Cc0).
The preposition "**in**" will be used for time too but it  is very probable that it is used less often than "in", as "in" is used a lot in mathematics. In mathematic "during" can also be used for  intervals of time.

**II** Pertaining to a mathematical definition in which no unit is stipulated only the preposition "**in**" would be used. The following ngram shows that the overall frequence of "in" is greater than that of "during": [in](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interval+at+which%2Cinterval+in+which%2Cinterval+between+which%2Cinterval+during+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterval%20in%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterval%20during%20which%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinterval%20in%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterval%20during%20which%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: No; OP must be assumed to be asking about the mathematical usage of 'interval' here ('_Define_ the interval'), where 'during' isn't used.

Comment: My case is actually not mathematical but more IT related. It's a routine that occurs at a configurable interval and that I want to document properly.

Comment: @Ullaakut What are the terms you use to define the limits of the interval?

Comment: The interval is given as an a number of seconds, is that what you mean @LPH ?

Comment: @Ullaakut Yes, so you have to give a time for the start of it (first limit) and a time for the end of it (second limit), right?

Comment: @Ullaakut Equivalently, you have to stipulate events that correspond to those times, right?

Comment: No, users should just input `5s` for example and the routine would run every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Ullaakut Then "in" and "during" and "over" are really the only good choices; "at" is not too good in most cases and "between" is really nonsense. "over" is better when the action covers the interval.

Comment: Surely 'input the start and finish times for ...' is the idiomatic choice now OP has clarified the question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There has to be a start time, the end time is nothing but a basic possibility and the duration of the interval can substitute to it and be enough to "define" the interval—I wont pretend this remark shows  anything new to a mathematics teacher here—but it seems to me that the verb "define" is sufficiently general to be deemed idiomatic (definition of words, definition of a procedure, of a mechanism, of concepts,…).

Comment: Spockspeak, outside mathematics and related fields (and hence non-standard elsewhere). // Your ngrams, not including 'defined', are not relevant as regards OP's sentences and in my opinion misleading. 'Defined on the interval ...' is the maths jargon I'm aware of.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would you have an easily obtained example, perhaps of your own making, showing this non-standard use?

Comment: [Even better](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167146/how-to-explain-what-it-means-to-say-a-function-is-defined-on-an-interval) (and on the correct site).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We can't apply the particular signification of "definition" as it applies to functions or again as it applies (differently) to intervals  without specializing it again. That is not how the definition of the OP's interval is to be taken. In maths the given object is said to be defined if its characteristics comply to the general definition of the object. The definition of function for instance is that of correspondence from set A to set B given that to x in A there can't be y different from z in B corresponding to x; (1/2)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If we say  that a given function is defined we merely say that it complies with the general criteria and that is one concept; that does not say _how_ it is defined; for this new sort of *definition* the particular correspondence must be given. The definition of the interval in the OP's question is a mere matter of fixing two points in a given  process. For instance, you can say that  the interval of possible correction of a comment is defined as the period that begins at the time of sending  a comment and that has a length of 5 minutes. (2/2)

Comment: The first 20 results (you can check further) I get in a Google search for "define an interval" are the maths usage. I'd say outside maths-related domains (and ignoring false-positives like _define 'an interval'_) the expression is unidiomatic to the point where we should say it's not standard usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why should there be only the concept of definition for mathematical intervals? You can talk of the definition of a word for instance, numerous concepts naming a sort of entities that presuppose a set of criteria can be defined. Intervals are no exception. See this (define this profession): google.com/…. then this one:google.com/… (I define this type of violence). "Interval" of a non mathematical sort is just rare, as "type of violence" above is.

Comment: 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is a pretty common, totally grammatical sentence nowadays. But it's not idiomatic. 'Exhausted, he decided to give the meeting a miss' works while 'Tired, he decided to give the meeting a miss' sounds off. Idiomaticity rules. 'The interval during which ...' is fine, while 'define the interval during which ...' is at best a poor example needing replacing. 'Define. and 'interval' are not even distant collocates outside the maths domain.